# ¿como enviar datos metodo post de 2 formularios en php?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

Cómo puedo enviar datos de 2 o mas `form` de `php` a otra pagina, lo puedo hacer es con un solo `form` que contenga una tabla, pero el diseño cambia totalmente y no quiero eso

```
<div class="form-one">
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Company Name">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email*">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title">
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name *">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Middle Name">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name *">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Address 1 *">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Address 2">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="form-two">
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Zip / Postal Code *">
        <select>
            <option>-- Country --</option>
            <option>United States</option>
            <option>Bangladesh</option>
            <option>UK</option>
            <option>India</option>
            <option>Pakistan</option>
            <option>Ucrane</option>
            <option>Canada</option>
            <option>Dubai</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option>-- State / Province / Region --</option>
            <option>United States</option>
            <option>Bangladesh</option>
            <option>UK</option>
            <option>India</option>
            <option>Pakistan</option>
            <option>Ucrane</option>
            <option>Canada</option>
            <option>Dubai</option>
        </select>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone *">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile Phone">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Fax">
    </form>
</div>
```

quiero enviar todos los datos introducidos en ambos `form` para recibirlos en otra pagina y generar un archivo con todos esos datos.

Comment: Parece un diseño un poco extraño, por curiosidad, ¿por qué tienes los datos en dos formularios diferentes? Aparte, ¿por qué no simplemente eliminar las etiquetas `form` que ya tienes y poner una sola envolviéndolo todo? El resultado sería el mismo visualmente (a no ser que tengas algo especial definido en el CSS)

Comment: me descargue una plantilla de bootstrap y la he ido modificando poco a poco, ya he probado con lo que dices pero se modifica el diseño

Comment: ¿Cómo se realiza el envío de los formularios?

Comment: usas jQuery?, simplificaria la respuesta de muchos.

Comment: el envio lo hago por post mediante un input type submit, no tengo altos conocimientos sobre jquery pero si puedo utilizarlo

Comment: Al parecer no tiene mucho sentido utilizar dos formularios en este caso, el tag `<form>` no es más que eso, un wrapper, ya el resto es los selectores usados en css o js.

Comment: lo que estoy haciendo en un checkout para mi tienda y con la plantilla que descargue tiene 4 form en una sola pagina yo solo coloque dos para un ejemplo

Answer (score 2):

Puedes introducir todos los campos dentro de un form y a través de un evento **onclick** llamando una función donde podrías utilizar un [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData) para enviar todos los campos por medio de **$.ajax** y capturarlos en la página php, me explico:

## Estructura HTML

```
<form action="#?" id="formGeneral">//form general
              <div class="form-one">
                            <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company Name">
                            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email*">
                            <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title">
                            <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name *">
                            <input type="text" name="middleName" placeholder="Middle Name">
                            <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name *">
                            <input type="text" name="address1" placeholder="Address 1 *">
                            <input type="text" name="address2" placeholder="Address 2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-two">

                            <input type="text" name="postalCode" placeholder="Zip / Postal Code *">
                            <select name="country">
                                <option>-- Country --</option>
                                <option>United States</option>
                                <option>Bangladesh</option>
                                <option>UK</option>
                                <option>India</option>
                                <option>Pakistan</option>
                                <option>Ucrane</option>
                                <option>Canada</option>
                                <option>Dubai</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name="state">
                                <option>-- State / Province / Region --</option>
                                <option>United States</option>
                                <option>Bangladesh</option>
                                <option>UK</option>
                                <option>India</option>
                                <option>Pakistan</option>
                                <option>Ucrane</option>
                                <option>Canada</option>
                                <option>Dubai</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="password" name="name" placeholder="Confirm password">
                            <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone *">
                            <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Phone">
                            <input type="text" name="fax" placeholder="Fax">

                    </div>
                     <button type="button" onclick="envioForm('#formGeneral');">Enviar Formulario!</button>
    </form>// fin form
```

Este sería la estructura, observa que el form se encuentra por fuera de los div, hacemos esto con la intención de abarcar todos los campos de texto y selects que existen, Los campos de textos deben de tener un **name=""** para poderlos capturar en la página php.
Para el envío creamos un botón tipo **button** donde agregamos el evento **onclick** y enviamos el **id** del formulario faltaria crear la una función [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) para el envío de los datos:

## Función JavaScript

```
<script>
// llega '#formulario'
function envioForm(formulario){
var form = $(formulario);
//Creamos el objeto del formData
var formData = new FormData(form);

$.ajax({
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,
    type: 'post',
    url: 'dirección url', // url donde enviaras los datos 
    beforeSend:function(){
        // acciones mientras envia los datos
    },
    success:function(response){
        //  response muestra los datos que devuelve la pagina php
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Para recibir los datos en la pagina [php](/questions/tagged/php) bastaria con un $_REQUEST['nameInput']; donde el "nameInput" son los nombres(name) que le colocamos a los campos, espero te sirva

Answer (score 2):

Lo correcto es que lo hagas con un solo form, los cambios de estilos serán mínimos.

Todo lo que no sea eso serán parches o inventos no recomendables por no hacer las cosas bien.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno si usas bootstrap, creo que va incluido jQuery, lo que podrías hacer es asignarle un id al div que tiene la clase form-one y con jquery enviar los datos al archivo que procesará los datos.

**EDIT: Se me olvidaba, los campos deben tener  el atributo name para poder ser capturados por el serialize();**

```
var datos = $("#id input, select").serialize(); // Aqui se almacenaran todos los datos.

    $.ajax({
        url: "archivo_procesador_de_datos.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "&" + datos,
        error: function(e){},
        beforeSend: function(){

        },
        success: function(data){

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo te sugiero un solo form y lo envias de esta manera.

```
var form = $("#Form_id").serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: "arch.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: form,
    error: function(e){},
    success: function(data){}
});
```

Ya que mencionas que se mueve el diseño de bootstrap, en los comentarios, tal vez es porque te hacen falta clases en las etiquetas, intenta implementar de esta manera tu formulario y te funcionara con el script:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-one form-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Company Name" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email*" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name *" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Middle Name" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name *" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Address 1 *" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Address 2" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-two form-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Zip / Postal Code *" class="form-control">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option>-- Country --</option>
      <option>United States</option>
      <option>Bangladesh</option>
      <option>UK</option>
      <option>India</option>
      <option>Pakistan</option>
      <option>Ucrane</option>
      <option>Canada</option>
      <option>Dubai</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control">
      <option>-- State / Province / Region --</option>
      <option>United States</option>
      <option>Bangladesh</option>
      <option>UK</option>
      <option>India</option>
      <option>Pakistan</option>
      <option>Ucrane</option>
      <option>Canada</option>
      <option>Dubai</option>
    </select>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone *" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile Phone" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Fax" class="form-control">
  </div>
</form>
```

Lo único que hice fue agregar las clases como indica en la página de bootstrap en su apartado de [formularios](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms).

Bien si no te detecta las clases `.form-horizontal`, `form-group`, `.form-control` puede que no tengas agregado los css y el javascript en la página.

Si el diseño no es exactamente a como lo tienes bootstrap tiene declaradas estas clases `col-xs-2` `col-sm-2` `col-md-2` `col-lg-2` para que acomodes conforme al diseño que tenia anteriormente estas clases te las explica en [grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)